# How to initialize a const char [] with a string literal

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, declaration, c-strings

I would like to do the following:

```
const char errorMsg [64] ( useApple ? "Error Msg Apple\n" : "Error Msg Bee\n" );
MyMethod ( errorMsg );
```

For a method with signature:

```
MyMethod(const char* errorMessageInput );
```

I have a method which takes a const char* and I would like to create a local variable before I send it in. I cannot allocate dynamic memory but I can use a larger array than necessary (in this case I made it 64). How would I get this code to compile?

Comment: `const char* errorMsg = useApple ? "Error Msg Apple\n" : "Error Msg Bee\n"`;

Comment: Or even just: `MyMethod ( useApple ? "Error Msg Apple\n" : "Error Msg Bee\n" );`

Comment: prefer `std::string` or `std::string_view` over `char*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of an array you could declare a pointer like

```
const char *errorMsg = useApple ? "Error Msg Apple\n" : "Error Msg Bee\n";
```

In fact there is no need to declare a constant array if the method parameter has the type `const char *`.

You may write for example

```
#include <cstring>

//...


char errorMsg [64];

strcpy( errorMsg, useApple ? "Error Msg Apple\n" : "Error Msg Bee\n" );
```

and then use the array as an argument of the method.

Comment: @zDoctor: This doesn't create an array on the stack.  The code has `"Error Msg Apple\n"` and `"Error Msg Bee\n"` as part of the binary, and this creates a _pointer_ on the stack, that points to one of those.